# Sending post request with sensitive data in php

Tags: php

I have an html page as below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HTML page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form method="post" id="myform">
        <input type="text" name="firstname">
        <button type="submit">send</button>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

from this form I want to send a post request to an api as follows using php:

> https://example.com/api?email={{myemail@gmail.com}}&pass={{my
>   password}}&input={{user input}}

this will return an json response which I then need to show to user.
I am new to php, any suggestion how can this be done securely without compromising my email and password which are hard-coded values.

Comment: have the backend do it via curl

Comment: the example you've wrote means that you're sending your input values in the query parameter. You may want to send it on the HTTP Post body.

Answer (score 1):

The first step to performing this API call securely is to use TLS (that is, make sure the form POSTs to an https URL).  Notwithstanding other SSL/TLS related issues, this will protect your in-flight credentials.  The other half of that is to attempt to keep your credentials out of logs, which translates here as "don't encode your credentials into the request URL."  Instead, put them as part of the POST variables.

1. User POSTs data to your PHP script
2. Your PHP script POSTs data to the third party API using TLS.  Example code:

   ```
   $data = [
     "field1" => "field1 value, perhaps as built from user's input",
     "field2" => ...
   ];

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($ch, [
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
       CURLOPT_URL => 'https://thirdpartyapi...',
       CURLOPT_POST => true,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query( $data )
   ]);

   $response = curl_exec( $ch );
   curl_close( $ch );
   ```

Of note: crucially, do *not* put your credentials into the `CURLOPT_URL` line.  Instead, ensure that you can code them in the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` array.  If the API does not accept that, then make your security choices as appropriate.

Comment: Why should it be a problem that the data is in the `CURLOPT_URL` if every thing is send via `https`?

Comment: @t.niese because it will appear in the server logs, in clear, most surely.

Comment: @t.niese because almost all servers log the request line.  And not all organizations understand security when it comes to logs.  In short, credentials should be ephemeral, and logging contradicts that.

Answer (score 0):

The example you've wrote means that you're sending your input values in the query parameter. You may want to send it on the HTTP Post body.

Also, by 'compromising' I believe you mean you don't want to send password123. One thing you should worry about (of many) is having a Man-in-the-middle. You can avoid it by having an SSL connection (HTTPS) or some sort of private/public key technique.

I've learned many theories back in school on different ways to login. Maybe you can try something among the lines of (according to your request):

Sending an HTTP request with the email value, api returns a key (can be stored anywhere per user or general - carefull with this one, do not share your private one), then after you receive it, combine with the password and sends the information to validate.

On the api, you receive the full set of information then apply whatever your logic is (combine your private key with it and compare to what's stored for example, or decrypt if it's possible, whatever validatio you have implemented).